# Default sound not working

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have two nearly identical Ubuntu (Mythbuntu 14.04.2) home theater machines. After setting up the first one, sound worked in MythTV, but not in other programs. I created the .asoundrc file and set the default sound device, and then sound worked in other programs (Firefox, VLC, etc.). However, when I do this on my second machine, I still can't get any sound unless I specify the device. Note that I'm trying to play the sound through my TV speakers connected via HDMI. Note also, that I think the first system was setup from scratch, while the second system was updated from an older Mythbuntu version (in which sound was previously working).

I've set up the defaults in the .asoundrc file like this:
`defaults.pcm.card 0`
`defaults.pcm.device 3`

I can run the following speaker-test command and get sound:
`speaker-test -c2 -Dplughw:0,3`

The follwing command also works and plays the .wav file:
`sudo aplay -Dplughw:0,3 ~/Downloads/test.wav`

So, as long as I can specify the device, it seems to work, but if I just try to play a video in VLC or Firefox I get no sound.

I've also noticed that if I run: "pacmd list-sinks", the state of the device is `SUSPENDED` and the cause is `IDLE`. However, when I play a Youtube video for example, the state switches to `RUNNING`, but I don't hear any sound!

Any ideas?